# NodeJS rmdir function error on LINUX ONLY?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, backend

So I'm running this section of my NodeJS script on my Windows 10 device running the latest version of Node and another version on my webserver running CentOS8 Linux. When this code is run on windows, it outputs what I would expect but when I run it on my Linux machine, it errors on this line:

```
fs.rmdir('public/u/' + info[0] + '/', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
```

With this error:

```
fs.js:136
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at makeCallback (fs.js:136:11)
    at Object.rmdir (fs.js:671:14)
    at /home/frontlinemist57server/celeste.js:156:8
    at /home/frontlinemist57server/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:279:15
    at getLine (/home/frontlinemist57server/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:166:7)
    at Object.nextLine (/home/frontlinemist57server/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:183:7)
    at Immediate.readNext (/home/frontlinemist57server/node_modules/line-reader/lib/line_reader.js:269:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Any ideas?

```
app.post('/api/purge', (req, res) => {
    // Get Sent Token //
    var giventoken = req.body.token;
    var authed = false;

    lineReader.eachLine('accounts.txt', function(line, last) {
        // If Valid Token //
        if (crypto.createHash('md5').update(line).digest("hex") == giventoken) {
            authed = true;
            var info = line.split("§");
            if (fs.existsSync('public/u/' + info[0] + '/')){
                fs.rmdir('public/u/' + info[0] + '/', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(err);
                            throw err;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Account Purged: " + info[0]);
                            res.send('purged');
                        }
                    }
            )}

        // If Invalid Token //
        } else if (last) {
            if (authed == false) {
                console.log("Invalid Purge Token: " + giventoken);
                res.write("invalid");
                res.end();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit:** Both Windows and Linux systems are running the same version of node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that DNF doesn't actually update you to the latest version of node for some reason. The server was still running an out of date version of node.

This is how I fixed it:

```
sudo dnf rm nodejs
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo dnf install nodejs
```